# How to force overflow:hidden for layered images within a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize, overflow

I am having two `IMG`s on top of each other within a `DIV` like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="somepic.jpg" class="layer" />
    <img src="otherpic.jpg" class="layer" />
</div>
```

With the following style:

```
DIV.container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 999;
    display: block;
}

IMG.layer {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Afterwards, I am casting some Dojo effects onto the images to fade one over the other and to scale them up, so that they will become larger than the `DIV`, which works all fine. But although I set `overflow` to `hidden`, I am seeing the entire images overlapping all the time.

So, how can I force the images to hide their overflow?

Comment: Try setting Div.container css `position` to `relative`. Does it help?

Comment: @JoshuaBoshi Yes it did. Please put it in an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Container should have css property `position` set to `relative`. 
If it has this property set, the absolute positioned element inside the container will count position relatively from the container position and so it will not overflow it.

Nice day,
JB

Answer (score 2):

set the container to

```
position:relative;
```

That should make it work :)